# VideoView not visible

Tags: android, android-linearlayout, android-videoview

I need to add a `VideoView` to a `LinearLayout`, and then to add `LinearLayout` to `ViewFlipper`. Here is my code :

```
            LinearLayout l = new LinearLayout(this);
            l.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,
                    LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT));

            l.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);

                myVideoView = new VideoView(this);
                myVideoView.setVideoPath(files[i].getPath());
                myVideoView.requestFocus();

                myVideoView.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(
                        l.getWidth(), l.getHeight()));
                myVideoView.setKeepScreenOn(true)

                myVideoView.start();
                myVideoView.setId(i);
                l.addView(myVideoView);
                vf.addView(l);
```

The problem is that I see all screen white and hear the video's sound, because video is playing but I don't see it. Why? Where is the problem?

EDIT :

if I put

```
myVideoView.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,
                    LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT));
```

it works but the video is not coming slow, as image appear, it appears suddenly. I want that video to appear slowly and to dissapear like this to.

Comment: As a side note, you shouldn't use "FILL_PARENT" - It's a depreceated label as it's misleading. You should use "MATCH_PARENT". Functionally it's exactly the same but is a more accurate description of the behaviour.

Comment: but MATCH_PARENT is available only for versions up to 2.2, right?

Comment: [MATCH_PARENT](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ViewGroup.LayoutParams.html#MATCH_PARENT) replaced FILL_PARENT in version 8. Under 10% of all devices still use a version lower than 8 http://developer.android.com/resources/dashboard/platform-versions.html

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
LayoutParams layout = new LayoutParams(l.getWidth(), l.getHeight()));
```

...

```
l.addView(myVideoView, layout);
```

Comment: still the same problem. Nothing changed.

Comment: and do the same for vf.addView(l, new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT));

Comment: Wait, later in the code are you flipping through the ViewFlipper? ie Calling `startFlipping();`

Comment: when video starts playing I call vf.stopFlipping and when it stops I call startFlipping

Comment: From what I can see of the documentation that will only stop the screen from locking/dimming while the view is visible. A ViewFlipper however is used to flip from one view to another to another to another. If you don't start it flipping it will remain blank (AFAIK). Think of you adding your `l` view to the second page of a book and then not opening the book. Try calling `startFlipping()` after `l.addView`.

Comment: I have no idea why you're using a view flipper at all. Just call `startFlipping()` and see if the video appears. Don't call `stopFlipping()`. Should give you a start.

Answer (score 0):

comment the line   myVideoView.setKeepScreenOn(true) and check once.

Comment: whether you have given background as white for layout or viewfilpper?

Comment: I didn't set background for layout and viewflipper

Comment: check by doing this :first add everything to your viewflipper and call  myVideoView.start();